# GWT Web Application - Using dom4j Gives Error : 500 Document Exception

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat

When I am running my application it runs fine until I click on Weather -> which is is a widget using jdom4j and Jaxen classes (in a JAR file). Why am I getting this error?, where should I look into?

```
 500 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 org/dom4j/DocumentException</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR: 500</h2><pre>org/dom4j/DocumentException</pre>
<p>RequestURI=/Samples/weather</p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)

    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)

    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)

    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:352)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)

    ... 24 more

</pre>
<h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:352)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)

    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)

    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)

    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)

</pre>
<p><i><small><a href="http://jetty.mortbay.org/">Powered by Jetty://</a></small></i></p><br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put every dependency in the classpath or bundle it via war. It seems so if dom4j is not on the classpath.